# Bootstrap Modal not opening on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a site that uses a BS Modal. The modal opens on a laptop and on mobile simulators (Safari Responsive Design Mode), however, when running it on a physical mobile (iOS 11 iPhone X), it does not open. 
[the page](http://sparkjpis.com/event.html)

Comment: It works on Android, so edited the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error on your event.html, this line:

```
if (width>=350)&&(width<=1200){
```

If you change it by:

```
if (witdh >= 350 && width <= 1200) {
```

It should work better